# How can running event handlers on production be done?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

On production enviroments event numbers scale massively, on cases of emergency how can you re run all the handlers when it can take days if they are too many?

Comment: Do you have a specific scenario why would you need to do that and it will take days in your case? Or you are theorising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on which sort of emergency you are describing

If the nature of your emergency is that your event handlers have fallen massively behind the writers (eg: your message consumers blocked, and you now have 48 hours of backlog waiting for you) -- not much.  If your consumer is parallelizable, you may be able to speed things up by using a data structure like LMAX Disruptor to support parallel recovery.

(Analog: you decide to introduce a new read model, which requires processing a huge backlog of data to achieve the correct state.  There isn't any "answer", except chewing through them all.  In some cases, you may be able to create an approximation based on some manageable number of events, while waiting for the real answer to complete, but there's no shortcut to processing all events).

On the other hand, in cases where the history is large, but the backlog is manageable (ie - the write model wasn't producing new events), you can usually avoid needing a full replay.

In the write model: most event sourced solutions leverage an event store that supports multiple event streams - each aggregate in the write model has a dedicated stream.  Massive event numbers usually means massive numbers of manageable streams.  Where that's true, you can just leave the write model alone -- load the entire history on demand.

In cases where that assumption doesn't hold -- a part of the write model that has an extremely large stream, or a pieces of the read model that compose events of multiple streams, the usual answer is snapshotting.

Which is to say, in the healthy system, the handlers persist their state on some schedule, and include in the meta data an identifier that tracks where in the history that snapshot was taken.

To recover, you reload the snapshot, and the identifier.  You then start the replay from that point (this assumes you've got an event store that allows you to start the replay from an arbitrary point in the history).

So managing recovery time is simply a matter of tuning the snapshotting interval so that you are never more than recovery SLA behind "latest".  The creation of the snapshots can happen in a completely separate process.  (In truth, your persistent snapshot store looks a lot like a persisted read model).